# Stripe : The default source of the customer is a source and cannot be shared from existing customers

Tags: php, stripe-connect

I am trying to use Stripe Connect on my website. I created connected account and customers but have a mistake while trying to share a customer to the connected account. 
I get this :

"You provided a customer without specifying a source. The default source of the customer is a source and cannot be shared from existing customers."

Hier is the code I am using :

```
function addSource($source){    
    $this->source = $source;
}

function addCustomer(){

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "description" => "Customer ".$this->getCustomerName(),
      "email" => $this->getCustomerEmail(),
      "source" => $this->source 
                            ));
    $this->customer = $customer;
}

function createAccount(){

        $account = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
            "country" => "FR",
            "type" => "custom"
        ));

    $this->account = $account->id;
}

function connectCustomer(){
    $token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
      "customer" => $this->customer->id
    ), array("stripe_account" => $this->account));

    $copiedCustomer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "description" => "Customer for xxx@xxx.com",
    "source" => $token->id
    ), array("stripe_account" => $this->account));

    $this->copiedCustomer = $copiedCustomer;
}
```

By debugging I saw that the problem happend when I try to create $token in the connectCustomer function. The customer is well added on my Stripe Dashboard with a correct source. The account is also created.
My goal after that is to subscribe the customer to the connected account. I have succeed to subscribe him without using Stripe Connect but now I need to use it.
I tried to find a solution in many other forum but did not find anything similar.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already too late, but here is something worked for me. I have had the same error. I have solved it by creating source instead of token.

So, replace

```
 $token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
      "customer" => $this->customer->id
    ), array("stripe_account" => $this->account));
```

with

```
     $token = \Stripe\Source::create([
                "customer" => $this->customer->id,
            ], ["stripe_account" => $this->account]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.  I'm not sure why it did not work.  Maybe some steps are missing?  Ran into the same issue while creating connect subscription because I was trying to associate platform customer with connected plan.  The error message was not very helpful.  I search google with the message and came upon this question.  C'mon, I was able to use the platform customer to create one-time connected charge fine (after I create a shared source).  Why can't I do the same here?  Because Subscription API required customer and not a shared source.  Stripe demo code wasn't of much help until I carefully read the first 4 bulleted points in the documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions (an Ahhhhah moment!)

> Using subscriptions with Connect has these restrictions:
>
> - **Both the customer and the plan must be created on the connected
>     account (not your platform account)**
> - Subscriptions must be created directly on the connected account (using the destination parameter is not supported)
> - Your platform can’t update or cancel a subscription it did not create
> - Your platform can’t add an application_fee to an invoice that it didn’t create or that contains invoice items it didn’t create

So, I'm just going to post some pseudo code in hoping it will help the next person who came upon this question with above error message.

1. You have to create a source (not token) to be reuse from the front-end/client-side javascript:

   stripe.createSource(card, ownerInfo)
2. Then you would use this source (stripe_token) to create a customer on the platform account (stripe_customer_id).  This can be useful with one-time connected charge (if you have a need for it).  This is also to store the original source (stripe_token) so you can create a new re-usable token/source later for the connected/txn_customer_id.

From step 3 on, all the codes are inside of chargeMonthly function below:

3. Make sure the subscription plan is a connected plan created by the platform by providing a unique name (3rd bullet point above).
4. Next, create a new re-useable source with the platform/stripe_customer_id.
5. Use the new re-usable source to create a customer (txn_customer_id) on the connected account.
6. Create your subscription with the connected/txn_customer_id and connected plan_id.

---

```
public function createNewCustomer(&$input, $forConnect = false) {
  try {
    // Create new stripe customer
    if ($forConnect) {
      $cu = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'source' => $input['connect_token']
      ), array("stripe_account" => $input['txn_account_id']));

      $input['txn_customer_id'] = $cu->id;
    }
    else {
      $cu = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'source' => $input['stripe_token']
      ));

      $input['stripe_customer_id'] = $cu->id;
      $input['txn_customer_id'] = $cu->id;
    }
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e1) {
    // log error
    \Log::error($e1);
    return false;
  } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e2) {
    \Log::error($e2);
    return false;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    \Log::error($e);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

public function chargeMonthly(&$input, $qty = 1) {
  $plan_name = 'yourplatformname-' . $input['amount'] .'-' . $input['banner_slug'];

  // attempt to retrieve monthly plan
  // if not found, create new plan
  try {
    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve($plan_name, array("stripe_account" => $input['txn_account_id']));
  } catch(\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e1) {
    // ignore error
    // \Log::error($e1);
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    // ignore error
    // \Log::error($e);
  }

  try {
    // create new if not found
    if(empty($plan)) {
      $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
          'amount'    => $input['amount'],
          'interval'  => 'month',
          'currency'  => 'usd',
          'id'        => $plan_name,
          "product" => array(
            "name"    => $plan_name
          )
        ), array("stripe_account" => $input['txn_account_id']));
    }

    $token = \Stripe\Source::create(array(
      'customer' => $input['stripe_customer_id'],
      'usage' => 'reusable'
    ), array("stripe_account" => $input['txn_account_id']));

    $input['connect_token'] = $token->id;
    $this->createNewCustomer($input, true);

    $sub = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
      'customer'                => $input['txn_customer_id'],
      'plan'                    => $plan->id,
      'quantity'                => $qty,
      'application_fee_percent' => $input['application_fee_percent']),
      array('stripe_account' => $input['txn_account_id'])
    );

    $input['txn_id'] = $sub->id;
    $input['txn_log'] = json_encode($sub);
    $input['recurrence_name'] = $plan->id;

    // success
    return true;
  } catch(\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e1) {
    // ignore error
    \Log::error($e1);
    return false;
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    \Log::error($e);
    return false;
  }
}
```